# Java & Asp.NET cross data

Tags: java, asp.net, jsf

Someone here is developing an app in asp.net (Visual Basic) as this is their preference language.

Now the method he's creating (as he already started work on it) will carry out multiple databases queries.

I have a java application i.e. Java EE that requires the same output from the function of the vb application.

Is there any way I could exchange the data as in send data from jsf to asp.net, process in vb and get output back in jsf?

The only data I require is a string consisting of 8 characters at the most. So not serious data to be transferred.

Comment: Need much more info to provide a meaningful answer. Many possible solutions: write to a file, use a web service, use a database, etc, etc. The details depend on your system architecture, performance and scalability goals, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The asp.net application can expose some [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) to your Java application to call and get data from.

This is very easy to accomplish with asp.net and should be standard enough for your Java application to call and retrieve the results.

Comment: I was thinking of using post to post the ID which is essential to query...then wait on that thread...then we function in vb computes the output string, post it back and I use get to retrieve it on my end. just thought there might be another way

Comment: @sys_debug - Yes, that's one option. Web services are more standardized, however.

Answer (score 2):

try using sockets as that is much easier to achieve. if you are brave enough use jni which us lot more hard work.